# submit button not working rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, submit, slim-lang

I've been having some trouble with my form in my ruby and rails application. I am using the slim template engine to create the layouts. here is my form code

```
= form_tag(:action => '/project/new', :method => "post", class: 'form-horizontal') do
    #####
    A bunch of input fields
    #######

    button.btn.btn-large.btn-primary.btn-block.disabled#go type="submit" Go!
    span.help-inline * required fields
```

When i click on the submit button nothing happens. No call is made to the action in my controller. Here is my controller code:

```
def new
    puts "HERE"

    redirect_to :action "show" , id: 87
  end
```

The 'HERE' never gets printed to my terminal. What is wrong with the way I am setting up my form? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
= form_tag(:action => '/project/new', :method => "post", class: 'form-horizontal') do
```

with

```
= form_tag({:controller => 'project', :action => 'new'}, :method => "post", class: 'form-horizontal') do
```

`form_tag` accepts 2 arguments: the path for the action and an options hash. You need to tell Ruby which is which by delimiting the first hash (or both) with curly brackets.

Comment: no error just no event occurred, it didn't print anything in my terminal either